# VB - Maths Quiz Check Answer

Tags: vb.net

I am currently doing a project and am trying to make my own maths quiz. Basically, I have 3 labels and a textbox. In the first and third label a number is randomly generated. In the second label, a mathematical operator is selected (either +, - or ÷). In the textbox, the user will input an answer to the equation, which brings me to the question i would like to ask:

I can do everything up to this point fine but i can't get my head around a code that will check whether the answer inputted into the textbox is correct.

I have tried...

```
 If lbloperator.Text = "+" & txtsum.Text =num1 +  num2 Then
        msgbox("CORRECT")
    End If
```

but it doesnt work.

In the end i would like to replace the msgbox with a counter to count the number of correct answers attained over the duration of the quiz. I have tried other things also and have been getting the error:

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

If it helps, a button is put in place to randomize the operator and the number in the labels and to check if the answer is correct.

Thanks

Comment: The problem with your code is that you use `&` which is a concatenation operator. It will concate the two strings into one, instead of checking them. Use `AndAlso`: `If lbloperator.Text = "+" AndAlso txtsum.Text = CStr(num1 +  num2)`

Comment: Thank you very much Visual Vincent, this seemed to fix it not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.

Given these functions:

```
    Dim dictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Double, Double, Double))() _
        From _
        { _
            {"+", Function(x, y) x + y}, _
            {"-", Function(x, y) x - y}, _
            {"*", Function(x, y) x * y}, _
            {"/", Function(x, y) x / y} _
        }

    Dim process As Func(Of String, String, String, Double) = _
        Function(op, x, y) _
            dictionary(op)(Double.Parse(x), Double.Parse(y))
```

You can now do:

```
    Dim operator = TextBox1.Text ' "+"
    Dim num1 = TextBox2.Text ' "5"
    Dim num2 = TextBox3.Text ' "4"
    Dim result = process(operator, num1, num2) ' 9
```

Please let me know if this helps and how I can expand on it to get you where you need to go.

Comment: I like that - a much cleaner solution than the one that I cobbled together in my answer below. Plus 1 for that.

Comment: Would you be able to direct me to where i could learn the commands you have used. I don't understand a thing in the top portion of the code sent, apologies for my ignorance, i would definitely classify myself as a beginner.

Comment: The two things you need to look up are `Dictionary<K, V>` & anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a select statement so for example try something t like this; assumes four textboxes below each other top one for first number, second for operator, third for second number last for result.  Converting to decimal to allow for people entering something like 2,5, case else allows for fact they may not enter a proper operator.

```
        Dim correctResults As Integer


    Private Sub CheckResult()
        Dim num1 As Decimal = CDec(textBox1.text)
        Dim num2 As Decimal = CDec(TextBox3.Text)
         Dim operator as String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim result As Decimal = CDec(TextBox4.text)

 Select Case operator

            Case "+"

                If result = num1 + num2 Then
                    correctResults += 1
                End If
            Case "-"
                If result = num1 - num2 Then
                    correctResults += 1
                End If


            Case "*"

                If result = num1 * num2 Then
                    correctResults += 1
                End If

            Case "/"

                If result = num1 / num2 Then
                    correctResults += 1
                End If

            Case Else

                Exit Sub


        End Select
    End Sub
```